# Why does the sequence $s_n = i^n$ diverge?

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently taking an first course in real analysis using Baby Rudin. I'm trying to prove that the sequence $\{s_n\}$ with $s_n = i^n$ does not converge, but I am unsure if my argument is correct. I'd be grateful if someone could check if there are any glaring errors in the proof. Here's what I have so far:

Take the distance metric, defined for $p, q \in \mathbb{C}$, to be $d(p, q) = |p - q|$.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that there exists some $s \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $s_n \rightarrow s$. Then, by the definition of convergence, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(s_n, s) < 1$ and $n \geq N$. By the well-ordering principle, there exists a *smallest* such $N$. Call it $M$.

Now, we have
$$
|s - s_{M-1}| \geq 1
$$
and
$$
|s - s_{M}| < 1.
$$

But
$$
s_{M-1} = \frac{s_{M}}{i} = -i s_{M} = i^3 s_M = s_{M+3},
$$
implying that 
$$
|s - s_{M+3}| \geq 1.
$$
This contradicts our hypothesis that $|s - s_n| < 1$ for all $n \geq M$, so the sequence $\{s_n\}$ with $s_n = i^n$ cannot converge.

Comment: The sequence diverges as it alternates between the values $1,i,-1,-i$.

Comment: Just noticed, and fixed the title. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof is not valid.  In particular, notice that if $M$ is the smallest natural number, then $S_{M-1}$ is not defined.

---

My inclination would be to show that $s_n$ is not Cauchy (if Rudin has covered Cauchy sequences).  If he hasn't covered Cauchy sequences, we can do a proof by contradiction as follows:

Suppose $s_n$ converges to $s$.  Then, there is an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$
$$|s - s_n| < 1$$
In particular, 
$$|s_{n+2} - s_n| \leq |s - s_{n+2}| + |s - s_n| < 2$$
but, by direct calculation, $|s_{n+2} - s_n| = 2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks, makes more sense. To clarify, did you get the middle expression in the inequality by taking $|s_{n+2} - s_n| = |s_{n+2} - s + s - s_n|$ and then applying the triangle inequality?

Comment: @onesix Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me.

Personally, I would probably choose to use the triangle inequality on $|s_N - s_{N+2}| = 2$ (we can't have both $|s-s_N|<1$ and $|s-s_{N+2}|<1$) rather than using the well-ordering of the naturals to get $M$. But that's just personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

Note tha  $|i^{n+1} - i^n| =\sqrt 2.$ If $i^n$ were Cauchy, we would have $|i^{n+1} - i^n| \to 0,$ contradiction.